# Algorithm with muliple Point structures

Tags: c#, graphics

Almost every time when I work on graphical applications I found that I have to apply an algorithm that I wrote in the past or found on the net that fit conceptually perfectly in what I need, but differ from data structures. For example I can have sometimes the "Point" expressed as a `Vector2`, or as a `PointF`, a `Point` and so on. Reusing such a code in different projects force sometimes to add undesired references, and always to do some boring conversion from-to the datatypes, so we evantually rewrite the algo for the new data structure. So the question: is there a (smart )way on abstracting the Point accessor in algo ? I think to provide something like a tuple of:

```
Func<TCoord,TPoint> Xaccessor
Func<TCoord,TPoint> Yaccessor
...
Func<TCoord,TPoint> ...accessor
```

but I have to do the same for setting the coordinates values, so I end with such a mess that no one **neither** me want use my algorithm implementation. How concisely specify the point coordinate accessor? Plus we have to take in account too that sometimes the point can be expresse by a float[]. I guess something could be done by using expression trees, but I'm not agile on that so any advice would be really appreciated!
Thanks a lot

***EDIT***  Implementing an interface is not an option, since point classes is not written by me, and reflection is not an option for performance reason.

Comment: +1 for your troubles but I’m pretty convinced that there is no good solution.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph, in such a case wouldn't be nice to have these structures in System as we have float etc ? Ie a Point2d/3d vector and matrix as always available classes...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
interface ICoordinate<T> { T GetX(int idx); T GetY(int idx); }

class PointRepresentation : ICoordinate<T> {
   PointTypeArrayOrWhatever a;
   T GetX(int idx) { return a.GetX; }
}

class MyAlgorithm {
   ICoordinate accessor;
   void Compute() {
       // do something with accessor.GetX();
   }
}
```

Or did I misread you? I don't really get your Xaccessor stuff...
And you should also keep in mind that this is probably going to slow down your algorithm..

Comment: Not exactly what I'm looking for. This means forcing to create a class wrapper for the point...

Comment: probably? you bet your *ss it is slower

Comment: Don't need a class wrapper as structs can implement interfaces.  This should be fine if you are only ever accessing values in the struct and your struct is truly immutable.  Performance will degrade slightly as I think the CLR sees the interface method as virtual...

Comment: @Adam Houldsworth, it's all true, but what I'm trying to solve is to have an algo that deal with any point structure written by somene else. It's pretty clear that I can implement an interface, but is exactly what I'm trying to avoid, this is the reason I'm asking ...

Comment: @Felice in that case no, they would all need some shared commonality.  Interfaces are the obvious one for that.  Alternatively, assuming they don't confirm to a standard, use reflection or dynamic duck typing to get the members you want.  Otherwise, you will need separate pieces of code for each differing structure.  This code doesn't need to be in its own DLL, you can reference link code files into projects from a shared area.